# Hovering over Windows Slider changes colour

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a slider in my Windows Store App and I have set the Foreground colour to blue. However, whenever a user hovers over the slider or clicks the slider the colour changes back to the default purple colour, can I change this to make it blue at all times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add custom slider colors to your `App.xaml` via styles, here is the list of standard styles for [slider control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709929.aspx).